Please identify this (Almodovar?) movie
I remember 2 scenes from a movie that I think was made by Pedro Almodovar, probably in the 90s.
In one scene, a pregnant woman complains to a friend about pain in her nipples (while they sit in a coffee shop).
The other scene shows that woman in her kitchen pushing a younger man`s face toward her crotch.

I'm not sure, but that might be Betty Blue, (1986), directed by Jean-Jacques Beineix.  I remember there being a woman in the movie whose husband wouldn't touch her once she became pregnant, and she became increasingly frustrated as the movie progressed.
